# Return 404 for non-www homepage and redirect other pages to www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to return 404 for home page of non-www domain and redirect other pages, for example i like http://example.com to give 404 error but redirect

http://example.com/a, http://example.com/b, http://example.com/c 
to 
http://www.example.com/a, http://www.example.com/b, http://www.example.com/c

How can i do the above using .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code in root/.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

##1)Redirect "non-www/a|b|c" to "www/a|b|c"##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(a|b|c)/?$ http://www.example.com/$1 [NE,L,R]
##2)redirect any other non-www requests to 404##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on

##1)Redirect "non-www/homepage to 404##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=404]
##2)redirect any other non-www requests to www##
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R,L]
```

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @User3476168 see the 2nd example

Comment: it is not working properly, the non-www 302 redirects to http://www.example.com/SFS2.x/notfound and other pages are meant to be 301 not 302

Comment: Clear your browser's cache,

Comment: I have done that, it's easy to see that the code your provided is not 301

Comment: You can change R to R=301 in the #2 rule to make the redirect permanent

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please try this